# how to reduce false positive alerts etc. Risky sign-in: Unfamiliar sign-in properties related to MFA login

Tags: azure, false-positive

how to reduce false positive alerts etc. Risky sign-in: Unfamiliar sign-in properties related to MFA login

following links in microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/768911/atypical-travel-unfamiliar-sign-in-properties.html

Comment: related to link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-risk-based-sspr-mfa